# How to find the eigenvalues of a custom operator using NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, physics

I would like to solve a Hamiltonian presented by a 2x2 matrix. Hamiltonian is given by:

```
Hc[z_, Energija_, Psi_] = 
  -((hbar^2)/2)*D[jedankrozm[z, Energija]*D[Psi, z],z] + 
    (hbar^2*(kx^2 + ky^2)*jedankrozm[z, Energija]*Psi)/2 + Ec[z]*Psi + Vext[z]*Psi + 
      HBR[z, Energija, Psi] +  HD[z, Energija, Psi] + HDp[z, Energija, Psi];
```

As you see Hc is a function of `z`, `Energija` and `Psi`. The equation that needs to be solved looks like `HcPsi == Energija*Psi`. `Hc` should be an operator that is acting upon `Psi`, but since I don't know how to define that I included `Psi` into `Hc`.  The idea is to use `NDEigensystem`. Something like

```
EodK = 
  NDEigensystem[
    Hc[z, Energija, ψ[x, y, z, kx, ky]*IdentityMatrix[2]], 
    ψ[x, y, z, kx,  ky], 
    {{x, -50*10^-9, 50*10^-9}, {y, -50*10^-9, 50*10^-9}, 
     {z, -50*10^-9, 50*10^-9}, {kx, -Pi*a, Pi*a}, {ky, -Pi*a, Pi*a}}, 
    3];
```

The question is: How do I make `Hc` an operator, and how to write the `NDEigensystem` part?

Comment: the definition of HBR seems weird, what # doing there? And I would try to start with a simpler, minimal problem and go from there adding more complex terms, as it is, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: This is what we call a "code dump". Not many people are going to be willing to take the time to sort through all of that and find syntax errors (which is probably what the problem is). You should solve a much simpler problem first, and make sure that that works, then build up from there. @tsuresuregusa points out at least one problem with your code. Address that first.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to make it clearer.